# incomplete type error

Tags: c++, friend, forward-declaration

Im trying to make class A a friend of class B.

```
class B;

class A{
public:
void show(const B&); // ##1## but this one works fine  
B ob;// error incomplete type

};


class B{
public:
int b;
B():b(1){}
friend class A;  

};
```

so my question why it's incomplete type? I thought that when I did `class B` it's like a prototype of a function which tell the compile there is a definition somewhere in the code.

also in the code above at ##1## why this is possible ?

Comment: instead, you can have the member as pointer to B (B* ob)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's a forward declaration and does not define a full type. You'll need to have a full definition of `B` before `A`, if you want to keep the member as an object and not pointer.

One of the reason for this is that the size of the class `B` must be known to `A`, since `A`'s size depends on `B`.

I suggest you `#include "B.h"` in `A.h`.

EDIT: clarification:

```
struct A;

struct B
{
   A foo();
   void foo(A);
   void foo(A&);
   void foo(A*);

   A* _a;
   A& __a;
   A a;  // <--- only error here
};
```

Comment: Worth noting that the reference is fine, because you don't need to know the details of a type to refer to it.

Comment: @AlexDan references and pointers don't need to know anything about the class in a declaration, other than that it exists.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : thanks but even If I change the argument of the function show from show(const B&) to show(const B) it works fine.

Comment: @AlexDan members can be pointers or references without knowing the complete type, return types and parameter types can be incomplete types.