# How to do C++ custom structured array subscript operator overload?

Tags: c++

I want to provide an subscript operator structure for the struct I am writing. I plan to do this with two `struct`s **foo** and **bar**. Code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct foo;

struct bar{
    uint32_t *mem;
    uint32_t *opcode;

    bar():mem(nullptr),opcode(nullptr){}
    bar( foo *f, int index ){
        this->mem = f->memory + (index%16);
        this->opcode = f->instructions +(index%16);
    }
    operator bool(){ return (this->mem != nullptr) & (this->opcode != nullptr); }
};
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, bar &t ){
    if( t ){
        return os << "bar:" << (*t.mem) << "\t-\t" << (*t.opcode);
    }else{
        return os << "bar: NOT INITIALIZED";
    }
}

struct foo{

    uint32_t *memory = new uint32_t[16]();
    uint32_t *instructions = new uint32_t[16]();

    foo(){}

    ~foo(){
        delete[] this->memory;
        delete[] this->instructions;
    }

   bar &operator[]( int index){
      return bar( *this, index%16 );
   } 

};
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, foo &f ){
    for( int i =0 ; i < 16; i++ ){
        os << f.memory[i] << "\t" << f.instructions[i] << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

I am using CygWin[x86_64] and Notepad++ as main compiler and editor on Windows 7 64 bit.

I have tried a lot of permutations on my own to fix this problem, but I would like to show the following:

```cpp
bar( foo *f, int index ){
    this->mem = f->memory + (index%16);
    this->opcode = f->instructions +(index%16);
}

and 

bar( foo *f, int index ){
    this->mem = f->memory[index%16];
    this->opcode = f->memory[index%16];
}
```

> 'f' is incomplete type error, with note that I have used forward declaration.

```cpp
bar( foo *f, int index ){
    this->mem = f->memory[index%16];
    this->opcode = f->memory[index%16];
}
```

> two forward declarations notes, and two invalid use of incomplete type `struct foo` on `this->mem = f->memory[index%16]` and `this->opcode = f->memory[index%16];`

---

I have tried a bunch of other stuff but it seems I have mostly an issue with `incomplete type`. I have searched SO for answers, and one did explain [what is incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration/553869#553869), other issue was [about recursive definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276134/incomplete-type) and [this one doesn't define how to make an incomplete type complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446494/incomplete-type-error).

I am hung on this for past several days, going trough iterations for simple operator overloading. Maybe I am phrasing it wrong in questions, or searching for wrong answers.

But can someone point out my mistakes and/or write how to overload array subscript operator with code and not just body less functions?

Comment: I made an answer but deleted it because I noticed there are a lot of other things that will break so to get on the right track: Skip the manual memory allocation. `uint32_t *memory = new uint32_t[16];` should be `uint32_t memory[16];` etc.

Comment: Where'd you put your "terminal" at in the above code.  Can you post a more complete sample?

Comment: @TJBandrowsky Yeah terminal was remnant of minimal executable example. When I realised that I typed *foo* / *bar* in question I just renamed it.

Comment: @Danilo Already edited that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic design problems (which don't relate to your question) aside, there are <s>two</s> three things that keep this from compiling:

1. The body of the constructor `bar::bar(foo*,int)` is defined inline, and uses members from `foo`.  Since `foo` isn't defined yet (it's an ***incomplete type***), the compiler chokes because it doesn't know about the members of `foo` yet.
2. When you call the constructor, you pass in a `foo &`, not a `foo *`.
3. `foo::operator[]` returns a non-const reference to a temporary, which some compilers might accept, but is just plain wrong. (spotted by Ted Lyngmo)

The following code compiles (https://godbolt.org/z/_F_ZpJ):

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo;

struct bar
{
    uint32_t *mem;
    uint32_t *opcode;

    bar():mem(nullptr),opcode(nullptr){}
    bar( foo *f, int index );
    bar (bar const &) = default;  // add default copy constructor
    operator bool(){ return (this->mem != nullptr) & (this->opcode != nullptr); }
};


struct foo{

    uint32_t *memory = new uint32_t[16]();
    uint32_t *instructions = new uint32_t[16]();

    foo(){}

    ~foo(){
        delete[] this->memory;
        delete[] this->instructions;
    }

   bar operator[]( int index){
      return bar( this, index%16 ); // this, not *this
   } 

};


bar::bar( foo *f, int index )   // moved the definition down here
{
     this->mem = f->memory + (index%16);
     this->opcode = f->instructions +(index%16);
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, bar &t )
{
    if( t ){
        return os << "bar:" << (*t.mem) << "\t-\t" << (*t.opcode);
    }else{
        return os << "bar: NOT INITIALIZED";
    }
}


std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, foo &f )
{
    for( int i =0 ; i < 16; i++ ){
        os << f.memory[i] << "\t" << f.instructions[i] << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

As I already said, there are some basic design problems and you should think about redesigning this code.   Something like [the code at this link](https://godbolt.org/z/xU5q1E) is better.  Better yet, ditch `foo` altogether use the refactoring suggested in TJ Bandrowsky's answer.

Comment: Would you mind answering why did you choose to put constructor bellow the `foo` struct?

Comment: `bar &operator[]( int index)` was one of the things I commented in my now deleted answer. It compiles and will probably end in disaster. Edit: Actually, it doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/oIJ5U2

Comment: @Danilo As I said in the post, `foo` is an incomplete type, You can't refer to members of `foo` until after the struct is defined.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Agreed.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, sometimes it needs some help: https://godbolt.org/z/vQiNGL (or in this case, silly much help. `/W4` is an almost unusable warning level). It still compiles with MSVC, but at least with a warning.

Comment: @Spencer, would you mind adding the assigment operator overloading since it fails for me ?

Comment: @Danilo I added a default copy constructor, which is necessary for this to work.   You shouldn't need to add any assignment operator.

Comment: @Spencer, why i shouldn't need any assignment operator ? There is implied way to change the values of memory and opcode of bar?  
  
Also I've run this code, and it prints foo perfectly, but for bar `std::cout` returns 1. This has happened before for me when I tried to print uninitialized structure.  Maybe my compiler has gone mental.

Comment: @Danilo The way you've designed it, you can't assign them separately.   And the assignment is ill-defined -- Do you want to assign the pointers, or what's behind the pointers? `std::cout` doesn't return anything -- it's an object. What makes you think it returns 1?

Comment: @Danilo If you are going to continue down this rabbit hole, at least read [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: In example you provided (from original code) ostream operators are overloaded. Which means that foo and bar are printable. Looks like there is serious language barrier from my side @Spencer. I don't know how to parse it differently. Ostream operators are overloaded, both objects are printable. When I try to print `f[4]` for example it returns 1, but it should return values stored at index 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider refactoring the thing to something like:

```
bar {
uint opcode, mem;
}
```

then make your machine model a std:vector and it would be a lot simpler.

Comment: What is machine model? I have tried using `std::vector` ... I had bad time referencing it since (and I've read this on SO somewhere) it can not be changed.

Comment: Well, it looks like you are trying to write something that emulates assembler, so a list of your bars would be like a program.  Therefor 

std::vector<bar> instructions.

Then you just loop through instructions ...the tell tale sign is that you are using way too many pointers for modern C++.  Instead of trying to roll your own collections, use the ones they have.

Comment: @Danilo What do you mean by "it cannot be changed"?  You can insert, delete, and update individual values of a `vector`....

Comment: @Spencer. I tried to implement subscirpt operator with 1D `std::vector` instead of 2 `array`s but, when I searched for the issue I was having (on some questions several days ago) it said that reference to item in vector cant change the value of vectors item.

Comment: @TJBandrowsky yeah, assembler is close to what I want to do, but every memory is tied to instruction, no looping over programs - just bouncing out variables between memories and their instructions. That is why I need to hold in bar opcode and memory, since I can then use operators `>>`, `<<` and `=` to set,get memory and assign instruction.

Comment: @Danilo You shouldn't need to implement `operator[]`. `vector` already does that for you.

Comment: So I do have 1 vector that holds entire file, but now I need to reference specific memory segments that are changeable, so if I grab 1 instruction, and its memory with offset of 16*4 bytes, that is what I need to access with subscript operator overloading. It seems much easier than running over whole file every time I need to access memory or instruction.

Comment: In that case what you do is change bar to like so:

class bar {
    int opcode;
    std::vector<int> mem;
}

class machine {
  std::vector<bar> instructions;

}

Now you have variable length memory, can access each instruction individually, and C++ does all the heavy lifting for you.